# CTE not updating all the selected rows

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, fifo

I am trying to implement FIFO on Inventory.

I have following tables related to inventory:

```
Lot:
ID,SiteID,WHID,BatchID,Qty,Amount,QtyRemaning,AmountRemaning,LastQtyOut,DimComb, . . .

Dispatch Note:
ID,ProductID,SiteID,WHID,Quantity,DimComb, . . .
```

I have a query which calculates the cummulative sum and OUT the stock based on FIFO:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  
        DN.fldQty as DNQty,
        DN.fldProductID as DNProductID,
        lot.fldProductID as LotsProductID,
        lot.fldID as LotID,
        lot.fldQtyRemaning as QtyRemaning,
        lot.fldUnitCost as UnitCost,
        lot.fldQty as LotQty,
        lot.fldAmountRemaning as AmountRemaning,
        lot.fldLastQtyOut as LastQtyOut,
        lot.fldLastUpdateRefDoc as fldLastUpdateRefDoc,
        lot.fldLastUpdateRefDocNum as fldLastUpdateRefDocNum,
        DN.DimComb as DNDimComb,
        lot.DimComb,
        CumulativeSum= SUM(lot.fldQtyRemaning) 
        OVER 
        (PARTITION BY 
        DN.DimComb,
        lot.fldProductID,
        lot.fldSiteID,
        lot.fldWHID, 
        lot.fldLocationID,
        lot.fldPalletID--,
        --lot.fldBatchID 
        ORDER BY lot.fldID  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
    FROM 
        #tmpTblDN DN
    RIGHT JOIN
        lot lot
    ON
        --lot.fldRefDocNum              =   tblGRNItems.fldGRNID                AND 
        ISNULL(DN.fldProductID,0) = ISNULL(lot.fldProductID,0) AND                              
        ISNULL(DN.fldSiteID,0)      =   ISNULL(lot.fldSiteID,0)         AND
        ISNULL(DN.fldWHID,0)        =   ISNULL(lot.fldWHID,0)           AND
        ISNULL(DN.fldLocationID,0)  =   ISNULL(lot.fldLocationID,0)     AND
        ISNULL(DN.fldPalletID,0)    =   ISNULL(lot.fldPalletID,0)       --AND
        --ISNULL(tblSIRItems.fldBatchID,0)    =   ISNULL(lot.fldBatchID,0)
    WHERE 
            DN.fldDNID              =       @DNID   
    AND     lot.fldQtyRemaning              >       0
)

UPDATE 
    CTE
SET
    QtyRemaning = CASE 

            WHEN (CumulativeSum - DNQty) < 0 AND DNProductID = LotsProductID THEN  0
            WHEN (CumulativeSum - DNQty) BETWEEN 0 AND QtyRemaning AND DNProductID = LotsProductID THEN (CumulativeSum - DNQty)
            ELSE QtyRemaning 
           END ,
    LastQtyOut = CASE 
            WHEN (CumulativeSum - DNQty) < 0 AND DNProductID = LotsProductID THEN QtyRemaning 
            WHEN (CumulativeSum - DNQty) BETWEEN 0 AND QtyRemaning AND DNProductID = LotsProductID THEN 
                CASE WHEN LotQty = QtyRemaning THEN
                    (QtyRemaning - (CumulativeSum - DNQty))
                ELSE
                    (CumulativeSum - (CumulativeSum - DNQty))
                END

            ELSE LastQtyOut 
           END ,
    AmountRemaning = CASE 
            WHEN (CumulativeSum - DNQty) < 0 AND DNProductID = LotsProductID THEN AmountRemaning - (QtyRemaning * UnitCost)
            WHEN (CumulativeSum - DNQty) BETWEEN 0 AND QtyRemaning AND DNProductID = LotsProductID THEN 
                CASE WHEN LotQty = QtyRemaning THEN
                    AmountRemaning - ((QtyRemaning - (CumulativeSum - DNQty)) * UnitCost)
                ELSE
                    AmountRemaning - ((CumulativeSum - (CumulativeSum - DNQty)) * UnitCost)
                END
            ELSE AmountRemaning 
           END ,
    fldDimComb = DNDimComb,
    fldLastUpdateRefDoc = 'DispatchNote',
    fldLastUpdateRefDocNum = @DNID

FROM CTE
WHERE CumulativeSum <= QtyRemaning + DNQty
```

Now I have the case where I have same ProductID with different Quantity and different DimComb in DN, CTE shows following result on select:

```
DNQty | DNProductID | LotsProductID | LotID | QtyRemaning | UnitCost | LotQty | AmountRemaning | LastQtyOut | CumulativeSum |
2     | 14          | 14            | 783   | 100         | 3        | 100    | 300            | NULL       | 100           |
3     | 14          | 14            | 783   | 100         | 3        | 100    | 300            | NULL       | 100           |
```

But the problem is, it only updates the Lot table with the first row with DNQty 2.

I have also commented the WHERE clause but it didn't work either.
I think its not updating the Lot table with 2nd row (.i.e. the row with DNQty 3) because the both rows refer to same row in Lot table (.i.e LotID 783).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is highly doubtful anyone will wade through this wall of code to begin to debug it. But I see a right join that is implicitly converted to an inner join due to the where clause usage - and that is never a good sign. Providing a simplified example using a script or fiddle will encourage others.

Comment: I see this: DNProductID = LotsProductID in your update case conditions. But this does not account for NULL values like your join does in the CTE. So, should it? Or is your CTE logic inconsistent and over-complicated? Much depends on your schema and table usage - something only you know.

Comment: @SMor: I Appreciate you for taking time to look into the matter. I tried my best to provide as much information as required to understand the problem. For the NULL check in update statement I already checked Lot table for Product availability before the update query.

Comment: Your problem here is spaghetti code, and the formatting and consistency of syntax leaves something to be desired as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think its not updating the Lot table with 2nd row (.i.e. the row
>   with DNQty 3) because the both rows refer to same row in Lot table
>   (.i.e LotID 783).

Yes, exactly so.

Your example can be simplified as this:

```
create table #tmpTblDN (DNQty int, DNProductID int);
insert into #tmpTblDN values (2, 14), (3, 14);

create table #lot (LotsProductID int, 
                   LotID int, 
                   QtyRemaning int, 
                   UnitCost int, 
                   LotQty int, 
                   AmountRemaning int,
                   LastQtyOut int, 
                   CumulativeSum int);
insert into #lot values
(14, 783, 100, 3, 100, 300, NULL, 100)  


;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM 
        #tmpTblDN DN
    RIGHT JOIN
        #lot lot
           on dn.DNProductID = lot.LotsProductID
)

UPDATE 
    CTE
SET
--select *,
    QtyRemaning = CASE 
            WHEN (CumulativeSum - DNQty) < 0 AND DNProductID = LotsProductID THEN  0
            WHEN (CumulativeSum - DNQty) BETWEEN 0 AND QtyRemaning AND DNProductID = LotsProductID THEN (CumulativeSum - DNQty)
            ELSE QtyRemaning 
           END 

FROM CTE
WHERE CumulativeSum <= QtyRemaning + DNQty
```

So you clearly see that your first table contains 2 rows, but you do an `update` of the second table (through cte) that has only one row.

The explanation of this can be found in BOL article [UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) under the section "Updating Data Based on Data From Other Tables":

[image]

> In this case I want to update Lot with ID 783 by subtracting DNQty 2
>   and 3 (i.e. In first update LotQtyRemaning should have value of 98,
>   and after second update it should have value of 95).

This means that you want to `update` your `Lot` table by using the `sum` of DNQty, so first you should write an aggregated query that calculates `sum(DNQty)`, this way you guarantee that every `LotsProductID` will have only one corresponding `DNProductID` (in my example. In your example you should `group by` all the fields that you have in your `join` and than use all that fields to `join` your aggregated result to `Lot` table)

```
update lot
set QtyRemaning = CASE 
                    WHEN (CumulativeSum - DNQty) < 0 AND DNProductID = LotsProductID THEN  0
                    WHEN (CumulativeSum - DNQty) BETWEEN 0 AND QtyRemaning AND DNProductID = LotsProductID THEN (CumulativeSum - DNQty)
                    ELSE QtyRemaning 
                   END 
from #lot lot
     join (select DNProductID, sum(DNQty) as DNQty
           from #tmpTblDN
           group by DNProductID) dn
             on dn.DNProductID = lot.LotsProductID
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I really appreciate it. It would be very helpful if you please suggest some solution/ workaround.

Comment: But what is your goal? Since you have one update of one row it's not clear what would you want to have as the result. If you want to set your value to min/max value for this row you should use aggregate functions in cte, if you want to set it to the "last" value use row_number() in cte with appropriate order by and then update using "where rn = 1" where rn = row_number() defined in cte

Comment: My goal is to update Lot table by subtracting the DN Quantity(s) from QtyRemaning column of respective Lot. In this case I want to update Lot with ID 783 by subtracting DNQty 2 and 3 (i.e. In first update LotQtyRemaning should have value of 98, and after second update it should have value of 95).

Comment: @user2517610 I updated my answer to show you how to substract multiple values in your update by calcucating first the sum of these values